# How to save Pyaudio recording as ogg directly?

Tags: python-3.x, pyaudio, ogg, oggvorbis

Is it possible to record pyaudio to OGG Vorbis? Currently this sample code records the output to wav:

```
print("Recording started.")
sample_width, data = record()
data = pack('<' + ('h'*len(data)), *data)

wf = wave.open(path, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(1)
wf.setsampwidth(sample_width)
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(data)
wf.close()
print(f"Finished recording {path}")
results["finished"] = True
```

Is it possible to record directly as OGG Vorbis without converting from wav to ogg? Thank you!